# Raspberry Pi network configuration issues

Tags: networking, ethernet

Ever since I made my Pi headless, and connected it to my laptop through Ethernet, I haven't been able to connect to the internet.

I followed this tutorial: https://pihw.wordpress.com/guides/direct-network-connection/

Using it I made my ethernet IP static, I can log into the pi from my laptop using SSH on that IP.

When I type hostname -I I get the following:`169.254.20.92 169.254.20.92 10.111.94.245 10.111.6.112`

My Ethernet settings are as follows:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
  address 169.254.20.92
  netmask 255.255.255.0
```

I don't know what the issue is, I've looked through other tutorials and troubleshooters, nothing seems to be working.

Answer (score 1):

There are many issues with your configuration which I do not have time to explain. See [How do I set up networking/WiFi/Static IP](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697) to explore some options.

The MAJOR issue is that you have specified a `link-local` address which is not routable i.e it only works over a single link.

If you have a router connect the Pi to this.